# An unknown or invalid jpeg marker type is found

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I tried to resize about 25,000 photos via a batch operation in Adobe Photoshop CS6.
However, I receive the errors:

**could not complete request because an unknown or invalid jpeg marker type is found**

Now, I did some research and found a lot of links already, for example: http://voices.yahoo.com/how-fix-invalid-jpeg-marker-not-valid-photoshop-7420332.html

However, what I've found is that these blogs either suggest a manual action to be performed on the photo OR to find the original image again (because current image may be broken for some reason).
On my photos, both suggestions are impossible.

Is there a workaround for this problem where I will be able to open and resize the erroneous images via a batch operation?
I tried opening the image directly in Photoshop, but then I also receive the above error. However, when I open the image in paint.net, I'm able to open the image, ensuring me the image data is not lost.

Comment: @Yisela: ok, can I move the topic there myself somehow?